# Using Roles in MySQL Azure - Privileges Issues on Admin Account

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysqladmin, azure-mysql-database

Provisioned MySQL Sever on Azure.

While provisioning created Server Admin Login Ex:  **mySqlAdmin**

Now we are trying to start creating Roles and assigning Users to Roles.

Logged into SQL Work Bench with  Admin Account ( **mySqlAdmin** ), which was created when provisioning MySQL Sever on Azure.

My Queries for Creating User / Role and assigning Role to User.

[image]

Its failing on Line 5 though the current user is Admin and got below privileges. (Result from line 1)

[image]

Error while assigning role to user (Line 5)

[image]

How can I assign **Super Privileges** to **mySqlAdmin** account.

I cannot see any options on Azure MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Raised service request with Microsoft:

**Response**:

At this time, it is not supported to assign DB roles in Azure DB for MySQL and we don’t have a time frame of when, or if, this will be allowed.  We are working with the manager of this service from the Product Team to possibly get public documentation on why this is not supported.  We can’t guarantee when or if they’ll provide any official documentation but, we are asking for it and we will keep you updated as we receive any new information. We do apologize because this isn’t the outcome either of us were looking for.  We do suggest pinning the following two sites as one is the Roadmap that shows upcoming features and updates, the other is where you can suggest that features and options be allowed or created.

Roadmap – https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?category=databases

Suggestions –  https://feedback.azure.com/forums/597982-azure-database-for-mysql